# warm/neutral/cool tone of one image

Tags: image-processing, colorings

I wanna determine whether an image belongs to warm/neutral/cool tone. I find Kelvin color temperature to calculate the average temperature of an image over all piexls. But the result seems not good. Can anybody point in the right direction to determine the tone of one image?

Comment: What do you mean by average? Arithmetic mean or geometric mean?

Comment: Arithmetic mean. Could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "result seems not good". If you disagree with calcualtion, it means that your eye has caught only main parts of image while computer process the whole image. It results in bias and possibly, neural networks can help you to find some patterns to make answer more "realistic".

Comment: @rus9384 "Average" almost always means arithmetic mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to point that determining the color temperature of the image is still an open problem.

If you convert the RGB image to [CIE XYZ Tristimulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#Tristimulus_values) color then calculate normalized chromacity to get the temperature, it works for pixel, kinda, it is a lot of effort to simply feed it a mean. Indeed it cannot work. The average over all pixels gives artificial color (if you do it over RGB it is not even chromacity preserving).

Whenever it is possible use CIE RGB (it is physical based color space, using the actual human sensitivity to colors) or some color space naturaly separating hue and lightness like HSL.

- perform [image segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation) or alternatively perform [edge detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) and subtract edges from [reduced image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization)
- take from results only big enough blobs - this is arbitrary and depends on the image resolution, but more than 50 pixels is good default value. Blobs are segments of the image with small inner variance - they pixels are similar to each other, not varying too much in intensity and chromacity.
- Calculate the average of blobs in the HSL space. Take into account the area and assign greater weights to bigger blobs (if blob spans over 200px it will be better perceived than 4x50px).
- take into account the placement of the blob (calculate how far it is from the center) [image: color ellipse]
  the the center is weight 1, slightly decreases to suddenly drop. This weights reflect what is better exposed (assuming that there are no important features at the corners, but it is safe to assume that the main focal points are in the center).
- take this weighted areas (blobs) average them in HSL space and now calculate [color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) - sorry for obvious link but the equations are ok.
  This method performs quite good experimentaly, some parameters should be adjusted per type of image, sorry I do not remember exact parameterts (proven to give good results experimentally).

Unfortunately your task must be heavily modified to reflect how people perceive images, how they neglect the color of edges (which give quite big boost RGB-wise). What they focus at and how they remember. By the way, the reception of the image tone is a bit skewed by the represented objects - the attraction makes the tone warmer while repulsion makes it colder.

So please take a look at awesome articles:

- Kraft, T. W., Schneeweis, D. M., & Schnapf, J. L. (1993). [Visual transduction in human rod photoreceptors.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1175412/) The Journal of Physiology, 464, 747–765.
- Ho, H.-N., Iwai, D., Yoshikawa, Y., Watanabe, J., & Nishida, S. (2014). [Combining colour and temperature](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4080700/): A blue object is more likely to be judged as warm than a red object. Scientific Reports, 4, 5527. http://doi.org/10.1038/srep05527
- Evaluating [color texture descriptors](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.01108.pdf) under large
  variations of controlled lighting conditions

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please afford me more details about the algorithm? Or some examples or papers? What does the blobs mean and how to calculte them. Moreover, does the color of the blob equal to the average of one blob?  Looking forward to your further reply.

Comment: @rockstone533 yes, the color of blob is the average of its pixels.

Comment: As for the weights referred in "the the center is weight 1, slightly decreases to suddenly drop"，can I use gaussian kernels?  And further, does the final temperature of one image equal to the  average over all gaussian-weighted blobs?

Comment: Yes, you can use Gaussian kernel (but it seems a bit too fast dropping. the idea here is to enhance the center of the image, not ignore the corners). Yes, the temperature is the average of Gaussian-weighted blobs.

Comment: I tried to divide images into blobs using [MMCQ](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/DDJ/1994/9409/9409e/9409e.htm). (In that method, all pixels in one image are mapped into a  3-dimensional RGB box. I choose the longest side to divide the current highest-priority box into two boxes until get predefined number of boxes. And then calculate the final temperature as you commented.) Do you think it's reasonable? Moreover, instead of Gaussian kernel, could you give some suggestions?

Comment: Yes, the median cut is very reasonable, as it will be immune to outlier observations. Maybe you could try for simplicity to calculate the distance from the center to the corner, store it and then divide every blob center by this value (value * ($1 - \frac{d}{d_{max}} * 0.25)$. 1 in the center,0.75 in the corner. The most important part, what kind of image (images) do you have? Closely related [dominant colors](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/) picker.

Comment: Thanks for answering again. My images come from daily news. I  tested  above algorithm based on Gaussian-weighted-blob in around 200 images. According to wiki, I mapped < 3300K to warm tone, 3300K-5300K to neutral tone and > 5300K to cool tone. Most of the images are labelled as neutral/cool tone, which is inconsistent with my judgement. Do you know what  problems may exist. Maybe the number of blobs? Or, some images may contain a half warm tone and cool tone. How can I get a better result?

Comment: By the daily news, what medium do you use? There maybe some kind of chroma shift needed. If these are printed, then accounting for fading, otherwise the limitation of the devices used / compression might slightly skew the results. Anyway, what is the actual goal? How do you tag your pictures? I mean are you sure you tag them consistently? How far is the tagging off? Since these are daily news, the outcome (your tag) might be off due to emotional content. I included paper about this, because the person tagging it manually will input own humor to the outcome. When you get half warm half cold

Comment: It should be in the neutral range. But this is heavily dependent on the images, and the machine evaluation is quite weak. There are too many factors to make it work, but some are still unknown (so it remains the open problem). I might only guess, but the model is intended for good lightning conditions and naturaly occuring images. It gives quite good estimate, far better than simple average, but still needs to be adjusted. I am not sure what is your end goal, also this kind of perception based algorithms needs adjusting by people. Have you tried to get labels from other people?

Comment: And the last point, the colors of your medium might interfere heavily with the results. Any brightness / contrast correction, type of screen, lightning conditions etc. It may happen that using one screen the image is warm, but will be cool using another device, you have to include this into the equations. But I would like to avoid blind guessing where exactly lays the problem.